# domain joining issue in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I am unable to join windows 7 os to domain, this is the error message

> > The following error occurred attempting to join domain, The network location cannot be reached

Comment: You have provided very little info on your problem What troubleshooting steps you have tried to resolve the problem? Have you tried to `ping` the DC from the workstation and vise versa? Try using `tracert` to see if there are any problems in between those. And also check this section of the forum to see the proper way to ask a question. http://serverfault.com/faq

Comment: hi thanks for replying, i have tried starting the tcpip/net bios helper service but no luck and also am able to ping my dc and viseversa

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the AD-server is your primary DNS server.

Also, make sure the TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper Service is running.
You can do this like this:

1. Log on to the client computer by using an account that has administrator permissions.
2. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **services.msc** in the Open box, and then click OK.
3. In the list of services, double-click **TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper Service**.
4. In the **Startup type** list, click **Automatic**, and then click Apply.
5. Under **Service status**, click **Start** to start the TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper Service.
6. When the service is started, click **OK**, and then **quit the Services snap-in**.

More info: [KB329866](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329866/en-us)